# How to create a list-group with custom checkbox in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a list-group with a label and a custom checkbox using Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

https://www.bootply.com/mEXshlUkcj

Comment: Yeah! Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="list-group checkbox-list-group">
  <div class="list-group-item">&nbsp;<label><input type="checkbox"><span class="list-group-item-text"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Default</span></label></div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"><span class="list-group-item-text"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Success</span></label></div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"><label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"><span class="list-group-item-text"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Info</span></label></div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning"><label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"><span class="list-group-item-text"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Warning</span></label></div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger"><label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"><span class="list-group-item-text"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Danger</span></label></div>
</div>
```

This

Comment: Please add more clarity to your answer by further explaining and formatting it.

Comment: If you want to format list group you can use by this way, the question is exactly this